# how to open image in our android application..?

Tags: android, android-intent

i have create app ,in this app i have edit image.in gallery when we select any image so we have get some option like "BLUETOOTH","Email","SHARE",so how i can add my application option in that list.?

Comment: Show us your code first!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By simply adding intent filter with send action and mimeType.
Example

```
<activity android:name="Main" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
<activity android:name="MediaShare" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.SEND" />
        <data android:mimeType="image/*" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Comment: it's work but selected image not come in the Activity or my screen

Comment: thanks for giving your time....!!!